# Изменение размеров блока в зависимости от размеров окна

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Здравствуйте, друзья!
Нужно реализовать такой код: 
1. когда ширина экрана больше 1024px, блок подстраивает высоту под размеры экрана
2. когда ширина экрана меньше 1024px, блок имеет высоту 1000px
Хочется, чтобы это происходило при ресайзе, то есть переключение в реальном времени.

У меня работает только при переходе от 1025px к 1024px. Обратно в реальном времени не работает, нужно обновлять страницу.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, где ошибка!

```
function heightDetect() {
    $(".main_sect_bg, .main_sect").css("min-height", ($(window).height()));
};

heightDetect();

$(window).resize(function() {
    if ($(window).width() >= '1024') { heightDetect() } 
    if ($(window).width() < '1024') { $(".main_sect_bg, .main_sect").css("height", '1000') };
});

$(window).load(function() {
    if ($(window).width() >= '1024') { heightDetect() } 
    if ($(window).width() < '1024') { $(".main_sect_bg, .main_sect").css("height", '1000') };
});
```

Comment: не совсем понятно, когда больше 1024 то меняем длину, когда меньше то высоту.

Comment: @VyacheslavDanshin извиняюсь, исправил. речь идет о высоте

Comment: предлагаю в $виндоу.ресайз вставить консоль.лог с шириной окна и в каждом условии по логу, для того что бы увидеть куда заходит рантайм и заходит ли вообще.

Comment: @VyacheslavDanshin можете подсказать, как будет выглядеть код? я новичок в js

Comment: console.log($(window).width())

Comment: @VyacheslavDanshin а как узнать рантайм? вижу, что в консоли значения меняются

Comment: console.log(">=") и console.log("<") внутрь соответствующих блоков if, таким образом вы выясните правильно ли роботает заданная вами логика. Либо используйте отладчик. Если заданая вами логика работает так как вы ожидаете - тогда надо искать проблему в другом месте.

Comment: @VyacheslavDanshin все, нашел решение. в начале виндоу.ресайз вставил $(".main_sect_bg, .main_sect").css("height", 'auto');

Comment: в таком случае не забудте дать ответ на свой вопрос

Answer (score 2):

После перехода к меньшему размеру экрана в css записываается height: 1000px и никуда не девается. Решил проблему, вставив автоматическую высоту в начале функции ресайза.

```
function heightDetect() {
        $(".main_sect_bg, .main_sect").css("min-height", ($(window).height()));
    };

    heightDetect();

    $(window).resize(function() {
        $(".main_sect_bg, .main_sect").css("height", 'auto');
        if ($(window).width() >= '1024') { heightDetect() } 
        if ($(window).width() < '1024') { $(".main_sect_bg, .main_sect").css("height", '1000') }
    });

    $(window).load(function() {
        if ($(window).width() >= '1024') { heightDetect() } 
        if ($(window).width() < '1024') { $(".main_sect_bg, .main_sect").css("height", '1000') };
    });
```